# Is there any part equivalent to LTC2326-16 or some way to do it?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

It is a very specific chip but it is not available in my region, from how I see the diagrams I don't think I can make another circuit, it is too complex but I see that sometimes they use several to form it, how do I know how it works? I am a theoretical physicist and I dedicate myself to microscopy and the equipment requires that chip, a fellow engineer has already come but he tells us that there is no way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: LTC2326-16 is an analog-to-digital converter. There are many analog-to-digital converters but most of them do not work precisely the same

Answer (score 1):

*”but it is not available”*

LTC2326-16 is available and in stock with both Mouser and Digikey which both ship to every corner of the world. Just place an order for it and it will arrive to your door.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/LTC2326IMS-16-PBF/4878299

https://eu.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/data-converter-ics/analog-to-digital-converters-adc/?m=Analog%20Devices%20Inc.&series=LTC2326-16